# Writing to one Entry field ends up writing to all instances

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I foresee having code that repeats, so I am trying to make it slightly modular.
This will be input/entry, submit/button, clear/button in line and display/text below.

This is my code at the moment:

```
import tkinter as tk
from pprint import pprint

class MainApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
    
        self.frame = AddConsole(self)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

        self.frame2 = AddConsole(self)
        self.frame2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nsew")

        self.frame3 = AddConsole(self)
        self.frame3.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="nsew")

class AddConsole(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.bottomframe = tk.Frame(self)        

        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.bottomframe.pack( side = 'bottom' )
        
        self.stuff_entry = tk.Entry(self.top_frame, text="Red", fg="blue")
        self.stuff_entry.pack(side = 'left')

        self.submit_button = tk.Button(self.top_frame, text="Submit", fg="green", command=self.submit)
        self.submit_button.pack(side = 'left' )

        self.clear_button = tk.Button(self.top_frame, text="Clear", fg="blue", command=self.clear)
        self.clear_button.pack(side = 'left' )

        self.added_stuff = tk.Text(self.bottomframe, fg="black")
        self.added_stuff.pack(side = 'bottom')

    def submit(self):        
        self.added_stuff.insert("0.0",self.stuff_entry.get())
        self.stuff_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

    def clear(self):
        self.added_stuff.delete("1.0", tk.END)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    mainAppObject = MainApp(root)
    mainAppObject.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

I am able to enter string data into field below and have it cleared, but when typing and before hitting submit text is shown as being simultaneously typed into all three entry fields instead of only the one that has been selected.

What is wrong with my code and how do I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: An `Entry` does not have a `text=` option, like you're trying to set to "Red" here.  I guess that's being interpreted as an abbreviation for the `textvariable=` option: you're saying that all three Entries should store their contents in a Tcl variable named `Red`, so they all necessarily show the same contents.

Comment: yep, that's it. I copied and modified a line for other widget that had text field in it and just left it thinking it won't do much. Thanks